# Change label of "Manage Space" button

Tags: android

I am making an application (a game) which does not store any data. So what I thought, instead of "Clear Data" button I'd replace it with "Manage Space" and when we click on it, launch my the game from from there only. I am successful in doing so thanks to `android:manageSpaceActivity="my.package.name.MyGameActivity"`

Now, just for proper naming, I want to rename "Manage Space" to "Launch Application".
Can we at all do it? I know chances are less since the name itself says,

```
android:manageSpaceActivity
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can we at all do it?

No, sorry.

Comment: Hmmm. Thought so. Just gave it a last try. Thanks @CommonsWare